# Auth Key can only be downloaded once. This auth key has already been downloaded

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am creating a Key for APNS in Apple Developer Centre, I understand the following -

Download and Back Up
After downloading your key, it cannot be re-downloaded as the server copy is removed. If you are not prepared to download your key at this time, click Done and download it at a later time. Be sure to save a backup of your key in a secure place.

But, even when I have just created a key and try to download it the first time, I get

**"Auth Key can only be downloaded once. This auth key has already been downloaded."**

Has anyone any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 7):

Even I had the same issue and I used Safari browser and I got p8 file instead of a text file.

I feel there is bug or compatible issue with Apple Site and Chrome Browser.

So I feel, We should use safari or firefox to get p8 key file.

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was having a couple of spaces (3 words) in the name of the key. After changing the name to be CamelCase, the p8 key downloaded fine on Safari.

Comment: My key name was all lowercase (no spaces) still did not work, but changing to CamelCase worked, thanks. I used Safari.

Answer (score 2):

I changed browsers (was using Chrome) whilst writing this, the problem must have lay with one of my Chrome Extension(s).

Firefox worked correctly and allowed me to download a .P8 file.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to turn off my VPN. Did not work for Firefox or Safari until I did this. Made a lot of keys and revoked them trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait a few minutes and try again. This happened to me after adding many p8 files for many accounts, so it may be rate limited.